# Cakephp- Date Conversion while reading from excel sheet

Tags: excel, cakephp

Using Cakephp, I am reading from an Excel sheet (I'm using Libre Office) and the date is not converted properly.

I'm using PHP spreadsheet excel reader to import the excel sheet into the database.

I'm not using any functions to convert the date given in the excel sheet.

In the excel sheet the date which I have given like this 04/10/2013 is converted to this format (AprApr/WedWed/2013201320132013). I want the exact date which I have given in the excel sheet.

I'm adding my code also here:

```
        $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(WWW_ROOT . 'files/excel/' . $this->request->data['Request']['file_name'], true);
        $excel->setUTFEncoder('iconv');
        $excel->setOutputEncoding('UTF-8');
        $excel->read(WWW_ROOT . 'files/excel/' . $this->request->data['Request']['file_name']);
        $x = 2;
        $sep = ",";
        ob_start();
        while ($x <= $excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
            $y = 1;
            $row = "";
            while ($y <= $excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
                echo $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][4];
                $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
                $row.=($row == "") ? "\"" . $cell . "\"" : "" . $sep . "\"" . $cell . "\"";
                $y++;
            }
            echo $row . "\n";
            $x++;
        }

        $fp = fopen(WWW_ROOT . "files/excel/data.csv", 'w');
        fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
        fclose($fp);
        ob_end_clean();
        $filehandle = fopen(WWW_ROOT . "files/excel/data.csv", "r");
        fgetcsv($filehandle, 1000, ",");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($filehandle, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    pr($data);
    }
```

Please help!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'reading from an excel sheet'? Are you running an import script where you upload an excel file? Or are you copying and pasting from excel? And when you say the date "is converted to this format", what's doing the converting? What methods / functions? Where/when does it end up in that format - once it's saved in the database? At the moment, there's not enough info to help you - update your question to include some of the info I mentioned.

Comment: can you explain more that, what you have exactly tried?

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable time. Problem solved. Modified the format in the reader.php file.